# Call ShareActionProvider from a PopupMenu

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the ShareActionAndroidProvider from a PopupMenu which is displayed after clicking an item of a listView. The problem is that the share menu doesn't display the icons as they should be.

[image]

another problem appears when I click on the "see all" item, another share menu appears!

[image]

```
public void openVideoMenu(View view) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.video_menu, popup.getMenu());

    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+ id);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sendIntent);
    popup.show();
}
```

The XML configuration of the popupMenu looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
</menu>
```

Any idea how to resolve this?